# AngularJS parse text as HTML in bootstrap table

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to display some text in a bootstrap table. The text should get parsed as HTML due to the fact that I need the `<br/>`-tags to display all the different links below each other. See [this](https://plnkr.co/edit/3QAbg9HbOgd5kEhYJZNE?p=preview) Plunker with my code.
As you can see I used the default `ng-bind` directive as well as the deprecated `ng-bind-html` but the text either is displayed as plain text or isn´t displayed at all.
Can you guys tell me how to display the text parsed as HTML ?

Here the code for my HTML table:

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Method</th>
      <th>$scope.other</th>
      <th>$scope.links</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>ng-bind</td>
      <td>{{other}}</td>
      <td>{{links}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>ng-bind-html</td>
      <td ng-bind-html="other"></td>
      <td ng-bind-html="links"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The matching controller:

```
app.controller('TestController', function($scope){
  $scope.links = 'https://www.google.com <br/> https://angularjs.org/ <br/> \
                   https://www.google.com <br/> https://angularjs.org/ <br/> \
                   https://www.google.com <br/> https://angularjs.org/ <br/>';

  $scope.other = "sample Text";
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML injected into template is not safe by default, you have to mark it as trusted.

```
app.controller('TestController', function($scope, $sce){
    $scope.links = $sce.trustAsHtml('https://www.google.com <br/> https://angularjs.org/ <br/> \
               https://www.google.com <br/> https://angularjs.org/ <br/> \
               https://www.google.com <br/> https://angularjs.org/ <br/>');

    $scope.other = "sample Text";
});
```

Is there a reason you need to inject HTML directly? You could have a map/list of links and use `ng-repeat` to render them in your template.

Comment: I tried to map all the data into an array but I have no clue how to display it. I have to test if the data to be displayed is a simple String or an Array

Comment: @JohnDizzle [Like this](https://plnkr.co/edit/3ZTN8P3yOfjVpYU46Jdk?p=preview) for example? Or you can have an array of arrays and simply add another nested ng-repeat.

Comment: The idea looks good, but my data is in a single object, containing Strings and arrays, so I have to first determine which datatype the next attribute is. I need a way how to determine the datatype in my HTML template

Comment: @JohnDizzle Why don't you preprocess the data in your service or controller then? Uniform the structure and then simply render it. You can use `ngRepeat` with both arrays and objects.

Comment: Can you suggest a way how to process my data? Here is the link to my other question with the whole problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38891926/angularjs-seperate-array-and-string-in-html-template

Answer (score 0):

U need to use Sanitize module: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/service/$sanitize

```
app.controller('TestController', function($scope, $sce){
  $scope.links = $sce.trustAsHtml('https://www.google.com <br/> https://angularjs.org/ <br/> \
               https://www.google.com <br/> https://angularjs.org/ <br/> \
               https://www.google.com <br/> https://angularjs.org/ <br/>');

  $scope.other = "sample Text";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-bind-html` and `ng-bind-html-unsafe` for that kind of purpose.

The examples are shown [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/service/$sanitize)