# AngularJs seperate array and string in HTML template

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, arrays

I have a little problem with creating a dynamic HTML template. To display some data in a table, I have to separate between an ordinary String and an Array. First things first: The HTML template is included in another template using the `data-ng-include` directive with a controller. The controller contains my data which is essentially an object with different attributes. The objcect looks something like this and contains strings as well as arrays:

```
$scope.data = {
    name: 'tony',
    city: 'New York',
    friends: ['Ann', 'Ben', 'John Doe'],
    postal: 12345
};
```

There is also a matching array with the attributes to parse the information dynamically.

```
$scope.attributes = [{name: "Name", id: 'name'},
                {name: "City", id: 'city'},
                {name: "Friends", id: 'friends'},
                {name: "Postal-code", id: 'postal'}
                ];
```

The `data` gets parsed inside the `HTML` using this code:

```
<table class="table table-striped">        
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="attr in attributes">
        <td>{{attr.name}}</td>
        <td>{{data[attr.id]}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

This works absolutly fine for strings but I have to somehow determine if a attribute of `data` is an array to display the single records in a kind of List using `ng-repeat` on the record.

I tried to use `Array.isArray(data[attr.id])` with an `if`-clause in different variations inside of `<script>`-tags but nothing works.
At the end the data of the `friends`-attribute should get displayed one below the other in the same cell like this:

[image]

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Lt024p9h/2/) is the code on JsFiddle

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: Something [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/Lt024p9h/3/)? All values are transformed to array and then iterated over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can isArray but not directly inside ng-show.

you can use it like this.

```
 $scope.isArray = angular.isArray;
```

so this way,

```
 <tr ng-repeat="person in persons">
   <td ng-repeat="attr in query.attribs">
     <span ng-show="isArray(person[attr.id])">
       <span ng-repeat="p in person[attr.id]">
          {{p}}
       </span>
     </span>
     <span ng-show="!isArray(person[attr.id])">
       {{person[attr.id]}}
     </span>
   </td>
</tr>
```

Here is your updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lt024p9h/6/)

Comment: This works great for me. I just had to add `track by $index` to the `ng-repeat ="p in person[attr.id]` directive

Comment: ok. you got what you need :)
if its working then please accept answer

Answer (score 1):

You have to do some script and html changes if the value is an array like this Updated fiddle here : jsfiddle.net/Lt024p9h/7/

Answer (score 0):

Do Something Like this.

```
<tr ng-repeat="person in persons">
   <td ng-repeat="attr in query.attribs">
     <span ng-show="isArray(person[attr.id])">
       {{person[attr.id].toString()}}  
     </span>
     <span ng-show="!isArray(person[attr.id])">
       {{person[attr.id]}}
     </span>
   </td>
</tr>
```